# Sheen and Sheen roughness exports as black values for GLTF

Tags: materials, export, gltf

Now with the upgrades to the GLTF exporter in blender 3.3, I had attempted to export sheen textures.

But the sheen & sheen roughness values only show black so no sheen is reflected on the model while viewing on https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Sample-Viewer-Release/

[image]

[image]

The sheen colour texture exports correctly.▼

[image]

Here's my Shader setup which I have tried to follow from the documentation.▼

[image]

If anybody could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

You can grab the Blender and GLB files from here. http://filedropper.com/KYePNkbG

Edit: If the filedropper link doesnt work. https://we.tl/t-Ut8sBHHWVM

Comment: Sorry if I might misunderstand something - but what you show in the screenshots on the left are the original exported textures? And they are PNG files or something like that? And they do look like this in other software like Gimp or Photoshop as well? Maybe there is something wrong with the viewer displaying them as black? Because if the image in the file is correct, I don't believe it's a problem with Blender exporting them. By the way, Chrome doesn't let me download your file because it says it's harmful to my computer.

Comment: I created those textures inside blender (using the image texture node in the shaders). Heres the zip uploaded via wetransfer https://we.tl/t-Ut8sBHHWVM

Comment: and yes they look as intended in other image editing programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reporting to the github, the bug was confirmed and fixed by Julien Duroure.

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1728

Workaround mentioned in the report comments.

Thank you to those who responded.

Comment: No longer a bug in Blender v3.3.1 Shader setup will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Sheen export to glTF has changed with the Blender 3.3 upgrade.  Blender's "Principled BSDF" implementation of sheen is not compatible with glTF's PBR definition of sheen, so the export takes a few more steps involving the Velvet BSDF shader from Cycles.

For full instructions, see the [updated Blender 3.3 manual on glTF sheen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#sheen).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, I have follwed the documentation my friend. I even posted a screenshot of my shader setup.

Comment: But I still do not get the expected results.

Comment: If it's not working as described in the manual, please file an issue on the glTF-Blender-IO project here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help.